# Use the Fermat-Euler Theorem to compute $4^{43}\space\left(\text{mod}\space{15}\right)$ and $2^{51}\space\left(\text{mod}\space {21}\right)$

Tags: group-theory

I'm really struggling to understand this formula so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Any thoughts of your own on this problem? What have you tried?  Where are you getting stuck?  Unless you provide some kind of context, it's likely that your question will be closed.

Comment: What's to understand? $\phi(15)$ is the number of numbers between 1 and 15 that are relatively prime to 15. 1,2,4,7,8,11,13,14 are relatively and 3,5,6,9,10,12,15 aren't. So $\phi (15) =8$. $gcd(15,43)=1$ so $4^{\phi (15)}e4^8 \equiv 1 \mod 15$. So $4^{43}=(4^8)^54^3\equiv 1*4^3=64 \equiv 4 \mod 15$.

Answer (score 4):

You don't really need Fermat–Euler if you notice that

- $4^2 = 16 \equiv 1 \bmod 15$
- $2^6 = 64 \equiv 1 \bmod 21$

Comment: Right you are: using these theorems and Chinese Remainder Theorem would have been overkill.

Answer (score 2):

If you insist on using Euler's Theorem then since $(4, 15) = 1$ and $(2, 21) = 1$ then by Euler's Theorem:
$$a^{\phi(p)} \equiv 1 \pmod p$$
Then we have:
$$4^8 \equiv 1 \pmod{15} \implies 4^{40} \equiv 1 \pmod{15} \implies 4^{43} \equiv 4^3 \pmod {15}$$
Which is much easier to compute. Likewise:
$$2^{12} \equiv 1 \pmod{21} \implies 2^{48} \equiv 1 \pmod{21} \implies 2^{51} \equiv 2^3 \pmod{21}$$
In general, simplifying the modulo operation with Euler's Theorem exploits the fact that you find the closest $k$ such that $k\cdot \phi{(p)} \leq n$ where you desired to find $a^n \pmod{p}$.

Comment: I'd use $m$ instead of $p$, which gives the wrong impression of being a prime.